# Delete Query not working in MySQL from a form

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='source' placeholder='source'/>
<input type='text' name='destination' placeholder='destination'/>
<input type='text' name='trainid' placeholder='trainid'/>
<input type='submit' name='deletetrainid'/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['deleteTrain'])){
echo "ENTER TRAINID,SOURCE AND DESTINATION TO DELETE TRAIN ROUTE";
echo "<form action='adminPage.php' method='POST'><input type='text' 
name='trainid'/>";
echo"<input type='text' name='source' placeholder='ENTER SOURCE'/>";
echo"<input type='text' name='destination' placeholder='ENTER 
DESTINATION'/>";
echo"<input type='submit' name='deletetrainid'/>";
echo"</form>";
if (isset($_POST['deletetrainid'])) {
    $source = $_POST['source'];
    $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    $trainid =  $_POST['trainid'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM trains WHERE trainid=$trainid AND source=$source 
    AND destination=$destination";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result){
        die("QUERY FAILED". mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    else
    echo "Record Deleted";
    }
    }
```

On clicking the button having name=deletetrainid nothing happens and the input fields are shown empty be filled again. No data/row is deleted. Any help please?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) driver. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/6634591) has some good examples.

Comment: Yes it is connected to a db in phpmyadmin. Plus the delete train is also coming from a form itself but still wont work

Comment: I fail to see the connection here to phpmyadmin.

Comment: Deleting stuff this way is unusual. More commonly, you would have an active/hidden flag somewhere within the table

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I can see several things that could go wrong. SQL injection attacks being just one of them, like mentioned @Luca.

But well, I did my **own** version of your code, and here's what I could fix for you to get the information somewhere.

```
<form action='adminPage.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='source' placeholder='source'/>
    <input type='text' name='destination' placeholder='destination'/>
    <input type='text' name='trainid' placeholder='trainid'/>
    <input type='submit' value'Submit'/>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $source = $_POST['source'];
        $destination = $_POST['destination'];
        $trainid =  $_POST['trainid'];
        $query = "DELETE FROM 
                      trains 
                  WHERE
                      trainid=$trainid 
                  AND 
                      source='$source' 
                  AND destination='$destination'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if(!$result){
            die("QUERY FAILED". mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        else
        echo "Record Deleted";
    } else {
        echo "Houston, we have a problem.";
    }
```

So, **FIRST**:
The information you expect on the first *ISSET* `deleteTrain` is not displayed anywhere, and not set anywhere, it would never trigger the form.

**SECOND**:
You don't need two forms, plus, only the second one had the method='POST' and action set, you could set that in the first one.. without this, you would only get the information by $_GET.

**THIRD**:
You forgot to put quotes on the text variables on the query. That wouldn't work since strings are required to be quoted.

You are bound to make mistakes (several of them, really), so don't let that pull you down.
Make use of things like: **var_dump**, **get_defined_vars()**, **print|echo|print_r**, **die()**...
Everything that can help you figure out what's happening with your code before you need to ask for help, so you can, at least, have a general idea of what's wrong and where.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you can't add attributes: `action` and `method`.
the value in **action** in your subject is `""` and that of **method** is `POST`